# sudo make install: permission denied

Tags: installation, ubuntu-10.04, sudo

I have a most annoying question about building from sources. I've searched for an answer for a long while and nowhere can I find one... I've compiled software from sources before and this just baffled me.

So I am trying to install python 2.7.2 from sources. I can do a successful `./configure`, also `make` seems to run fine. But when I do `sudo make install`, I get a variety of errors...

First, `sudo make install` gives me this:

```
make: stat: GNUmakefile: Permission denied
make: stat: makefile: Permission denied
make: stat: Makefile: Permission denied
make: stat: install: Permission denied
make: *** No rule to make target `install'. Stop.
```

So I did `chmod +rx Makefile*`. To no avail.

Then, `sudo ls .` says

```
ls: cannot access .: Permission denied
```

Then `ls -d .` says the permissions are `drwxr-x---`

Then, as a desperate measure, `chmod +rx .`. That gave me:

```
make: stat: Modules/config.c.in: Permission denied
make: *** No rule to make target `Modules/config.c.in', needed by `Makefile'. Stop.
```

So some progress... What is happening here? It looks like some sort of permission problem. I presumed that sudo would be the solution but clearly there is something else going on here... I tried `sudo -s` but I get those permission problems all over again...

I am using Ubuntu 10.04LTS.

Comment: You're not doing this on an NFS volume by chance, are you?

Comment: Yes, I am doing it on an NFS volume. I am the owner of the files. My home directory is pulled off NFS. And my files are somewhere on that mount. I am trying to install on the local machine (so, compile files on my NFS mount, install on local computer, where I am on the sudoers list).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I believe what you are hitting is actually an NFS policy called "root squash". It's not uncommon for users to need root on a particular host, but you don't want them to have the same sort of privileges on the shared NFS volumes. Thus, giving local root access doesn't allow a user to run roughshod over any mounted NFS volumes and access/modify the files of other users -- the NFS server will map root's uid from 0 to 65534 (`nobody`), which is why you can't even list the directory in your on example.

So, that leaves you with a couple options:

1. You can try to make all the files accessible to `nobody` in your build by doing a `chmod -R o+rw .` at the top level directory, giving "others" read/write permissions on your files (may or may not be enough -- for example you might need to `o+x` directories if it needs to search them).
2. If you have access to the NFS server's `/etc/exports` file, then you could disable root squash (perhaps not a great idea).
3. Just build in a local directory like `/usr/local/src`, `/usr/src`, `/tmp` etc, or just create your own local directory (you can even make it owned by your user) like `/scratch/myuser`. This is probably the option that causes the fewest headaches.

Comment: Thank you! That worked perfectly. I used option 3 as it was the easiest (and 2 was not possible). It makes much more sense now...

Comment: worked for me too while installing ruby from source. Initially the build location was `~/downloads/ruby-2.4.0`. `./configure, make` worked, but `sudo make install` gave error: `:~/downloads/ruby-2.4.0$ sudo make install
make: stat: GNUmakefile: Permission denied
make: stat: makefile: Permission denied
make: stat: Makefile: Permission denied
make: stat: install: Permission denied
make: *** No rule to make target `install'.  Stop.
``` .  Ran the above steps by copying source files to /tmp and `sudo make install` worked fine. `/usr/local/src, /usr/src` did not work due to  permission errors

Comment: another workaround is to `sudo chown` the target directories to yourself, run the install, and `sudo chown` them and the installed files back to root.

Answer (score 0):

If your are using sshfs, mount using `-o allow_other` option

```
$ sudo sshfs -o allow_other hostfolder localfolder
```

before that you have to set `user_allow_other` in **/etc/fuse.conf**

Answer (score -1):

Try chown-ing it to your user. That is, use "sudo chown user ./*" (replacing user with your username) when in the directory and it will change the owner of all the files in the directory to you.

Comment: I am the owner of the files. They live in my home directory.